# C++ How can I take a string out of a Char array then save it as a separate string to later parse?

Tags: c++, string, char, getline

So basically I have to take in a series of numbers and characters and they would come in like this:
"2.1 3 +"

I save this in a char array then I convert it to a string but it only reads the 2.1 and displays that. So I am assuming its only saving the 2.1 in to the string. How do I get it so that my string is "2.1 3 +"?

Here is my code so far:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::end;
    using std::string;
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        float o1, o2; 
        string op; 
        char arg[20];
        cin >> arg;
        string command(arg);
        cout << command;
    
    
    }
```

Comment: `cin` stops at the first space. Make `arg` a string and do `std::getline(std::cin, arg)`. Why do you need to make a `char` array first anyway?

Comment: If you want o keep the `char` array and the spaces, maybe use something like `fgets` defined in `<cstdio>`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 ur right I just decided to use a string instead of a char array i thought the information was supposed to be sent in as a char array but thats not the case for this problem

Comment: Alright, glad I could help.